# Algebraic representation of an absolute value.

Tags: absolute-value

I tried several ways, but i could not come up with any way to have an equation as such:

```
|n| = ...
```

without using the absolute value signs on the right side of the equation.

I do not know if there is any way...

I tried using some form of `n * i^(an + b)` but those efforts were futile.
And I couldn't think of any other way to approach this.

Comment: I'm guessing you want a single expression, and not a different expression for $n<0$ and $n>0$? Maybe Fourier transform?

Comment: $|n|=\begin{cases}
n \text{  if n }>0 \\
-n \text{ if n }\le 0 \\
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to note that the square root has "branches":

$$(\sqrt n)^2=n\tag 1$$

$$\sqrt{n^2}=|n|\tag 2$$

Note that $(1)$ would dip into the imaginary numbers for a moment if $n\lt 0$.  $(2)$ is true because the square root of a number is one of two solutions to the equation involving the square.

$$x^2=4,x=2,-2$$

$$\sqrt 4=2,-\sqrt 4=-2$$

Comment: I thought of this, but I wasn't sure if it was completely correct, as it felt dirty, since square roots technically have two solutions... Does n^(1/2) also have 2 solutions since it is equivalent to the square root? I was hoping for a very definite equation, but this works. Thanks

Comment: Yes, $n^{\frac 12}$ has the same two branches as the square root.

Comment: Further, the $n$th root creates branches in the same way, consider the $\arg$ function in complex analysis.