# Is there an algebraic equation for Absolute Value?

Tags: absolute-value

There is probably no reason for me to need this, but I was just curious if you could theoretically form an algebraic equation as a replacement for the absolute value function. It may already exist, but I searched for a little while and couldn't find one, including the other question on here where the only solution enters imaginary numbers. I feel like I was getting close with

f(x) = x*(blah)

where blah would just be 1 either with or without the negative based on what f(x) is.

Sorry if this seems like an insignificant question!

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}$ (try typing it into Desmos.com)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Algebraic representation of an absolute value.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541593/algebraic-representation-of-an-absolute-value)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger That completely skipped over my mind! Thanks.